# Jquery - How to check if textbox has specific text and if so change image source?

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox. When i click my button, i want to check if the textbox contains "good". If it contains "good" i want to change an image next to the textbox. 
Is this possible and if so, how should i do it?
If you don't understand, ask me

**Update**
I found it on my own:

```
 var text = $('#m1-schaarste-textField1').val()
 var comparingText = 'good'
 if(text == comparingText){
  $('#image').attr('src', '/images/good.png');
 }
 else {
  $('#image').attr('src', '/images/bad.png');
 }
```

Comment: Yes.  Try writing some code and if/when you get stuck, come back here.

Comment: What's your HTML? jQuery, and JavaScript in general, is dependant on your mark-up. To answer this question we need to know what we're working with and, also, *how* should the image be changed in response to the text being present or absent?

Comment: Try something, and ask here if you run into problems with the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
if( $('#txtId').text().indexOf("sometext") !== -1)
{
    document.getElementById('imgId').url = "url"; //or
    //$('#imgId')[0].src = "url";         
}
```

Comment: That doesn't test if the string is *in* the text, it checks if the string *is* the text. You should probably use `indexOf() > -1`.

Comment: `!==` please use strict comparison as it's safer.

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas, so nice of you, nice way to point out mistake.

Comment: Thanks @Lavabeams changed, does this meters for numbers?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb you are better to always use `strict` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#textbox').text();
    if(text.indexOf('good') != -1 {
        $('#image').attr('src', 'src_to_other_image');
    }
});
```

Make sure to use the correct id/classes for the selectors.

Edit: Missed that you don't want a exact match but just see if the textarea contains 'good', updated my code to reflect this. Sorry.

Comment: how should i format the 'src_to_other_image'? can i just put there /images/good.png